Limiting Date {Axis X} and date {Axis Y}
I am new on Vega-lite and I appreciate if you could give me some help to solve my Line Chart with Point Markers problem, please.
I am trying to plot a graph that shows Artist Name (Sum) in Axis Y and Released Year (of a music) in Axis X, and I wanto to compare with three playlists (Spotify, Deezer and Apple).
But because evething is appearing tohether and tight like in the picture, I dont know what to do.
function ex02(divWidth) {
    return {
        spec: {
            width: divWidth,
            data: {
                values: spotify
            },
            "transform": [{
                "filter":{ 
                    "field": "in_spotify_playlists", 
                    "range": [50, 100]},
                }],
            "mark": {
                "type":"line",
                "point":"true",
                "clipe":"true"
            },
            "encoding":{
                "x":{
                    "timeUnit":"year", 
                    "field":"released_year",
                    "type":"temporal"
                },
                "y":{
                    "aggregate":"mean", 
                    "field":"in_spotify_playlists", 
                    "type":"quantitative"
                },
                "color": {"field": "artist(s)_name", "type": "nominal"}
            }
        }
    }
}

I am trying to make something comared to https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/line_overlay.html
I am using this dataset https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nelgiriyewithana/top-spotify-songs-2023
Thanks!!!

Please make an example with vega editor with the kaggle API URL so we can run some tests.
